# read_csv() with german special character in path

Tags: r, character-encoding, tidyr, readr

I am trying to import a CSV, but my windows username has an "ö" in it.

```
library(tidyverse)
persons <- read_csv("./data/persons.csv")
```

This is the error message (anonymized)

> Error in guess_header_(datasource, tokenizer, locale) :    Cannot read
>   file C:/Users/[...]Ã¶[...]/Desktop/data/persons.csv: The system
>   cannot find the path specified.

[...] replacement to hide the real name.

read.csv works just fine: `persons <- read.csv("./data/persons.csv")`

I am on a company PC, probably cannot change my Username.

**That's what happens if I use the RStudio GUI.** [image]

**Github tidyverse bug:**

[This](https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/834) might be related, but I cannot deduce if they fixed it.

Comment: Can you use file explorer to select the file you want to read from "Import Dataset" option?

Comment: no, see updatetd question. @RonakShah Is that what you meant?

Comment: Not solving your real problem but a workaround could be move the csv to another path where you don't have such characters and then read it from there.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good start and will work as a quick workaround until there is a better solution or workaround. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "German")` before running the read_csv command?

Comment: @Prometheus thank you for the suggestion. I have tried it right now, but it gives me the same error.